# Google Big table Filter with Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-bigtable

I want to filter all rows that match this condition: with input value `x`, return all records between two quantifier values in Java.

Example: With input value `x = 15`,

a record with quantifier `q1 = 10` and `q2 = 20` will match,
a record  with quantifier `q1 = 1` and `q2 = 10` will not match

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to filter rows that contain min numerical *qualifier* that is < x, as well as containing a max numerical *qualifier* that is > x , and then maybe you are trying to filter data from those rows, that are between those qualifiers.

This is pretty much the opposite sort of access pattern that one tries to achieve when setting up a BigTable. This has a code smell. Having said that, you can succesfully achieve this sort of query, using a combination of filters. However, these filters cannot be chained together, as far as I can tell.

First, use a filter to get keys with a cq < x. Next, send a query to bigtable per each key from the first filter, and filter on key as well as filter such that cq > x. This is an optimized way. An even more optimized way might be to limit the first filter to 1 element (i.e. get the min element), and only query without a limit on the lessThen portion, after the second step.

My implementation below is slightly more naive, in that the second step filters only on cq > x, and not keys from the first step. But the gist is the same:

```
  val x = "15"
        val a = new mutable.HashMap[ByteString, Row]
        val b = new mutable.HashMap[ByteString, Row]
        val c = new mutable.HashMap[ByteString, Row]
        dataClient.readRows( Query.create(tableId)
          .filter(Filters.FILTERS.qualifier().rangeWithinFamily("cf").startClosed(Int.MinValue.toString.padTo(Ints.max(Int.MinValue.toString.length, Int.MaxValue.toString.length), "0").toString()).endOpen(x.padTo(Ints.max(Int.MinValue.toString.length, Int.MaxValue.toString.length), "0").toString()
          )))
          .forEach(r => a.put(r.getKey, r))
        dataClient.readRows(Query.create(tableId)
          .filter(Filters.FILTERS.qualifier().rangeWithinFamily("cf").startOpen(x).endClosed(Int.MaxValue.toString.padTo(Ints.max(Int.MinValue.toString.length, Int.MaxValue.toString.length), "0").toString()))
          )
          .forEach(r => b.put(r.getKey, r))
        dataClient.readRows(Query.create(tableId)
          .filter(Filters.FILTERS.qualifier().exactMatch(x)))
          .forEach(r => c.put(r.getKey, r))
        val all_cells = a.keys.toSet.intersect(b.keys.toSet).flatMap(k => a.get(k).map(_.getCells).get.toArray.toSeq ++ b.get(k).map(_.getCells).get.toArray.toSeq
          ++ c.get(k).map(_.getCells).get.toArray.toSeq)
```

Can you tell me more about your use case?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a filter on a range of values, but it will depend on how you are encoding them. If they are encoded as strings, you would use the ValueRange filter like so:

```
  Filter filter = FILTERS.value().range().startClosed("10").endClosed("20");
```

Then perform your read with the filter

```
    try (BigtableDataClient dataClient = BigtableDataClient.create(projectId, instanceId)) {
      Query query = Query.create(tableId).filter(filter);
      ServerStream<Row> rows = dataClient.readRows(query);
      for (Row row : rows) {
        printRow(row);
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println(
          "Unable to initialize service client, as a network error occurred: \n" + e.toString());
    }
```

You can also pass bytes to the range, so if your numbers are encoded in some way, you could encode them as bytes in the same way and pass that into `startClosed` and `endClosed`.

You can read more about [filters in the Cloud Bigtable Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/using-filters#value-range).

Comment: I want to filter based on the input value, not the quantifier. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here I think